# YouTube player android Api doesn't hide progressbar when playing

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I use YouTube Player android Api to play some videos,Now I can seccess to play video ,but I found one problem is that the player doesn't hide progressbar when playing.You can see that in this picture:
 [image]
Actually the player is playing.
I found one usege thing:when I use YouTube in lower version such as 10.36.52,it works!But now I install the newest YoutuBe version(11.29.55),it donse't work.
And this is my code:
player xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true" >
    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
private void initYouTubePlayerView() {
    YouTubePlayerView playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    playerView.initialize(YoutubeConnector.KEY,this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                    boolean restored) {
    if (player == null) return;
    PlayerActivity.this.mPlayer = player;
    mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
    if(!restored) {
        player.loadVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID"));
        Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationSuccess: " + getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID"));
    }
    mPlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(new PlaybackEventListener());
    mPlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener());
}
```

And the YouTube Api version is newest.

Comment: I forget one thing: This app is running on Android TV Box,I don't know running in android phone this problem would occure or not.

Comment: Try setting the `mPlayer.setFullScreen(true);` in `onInitializationSuccess()`.

Comment: @Abbas I tried that,but can't work...And  I found that if I remove  `mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);` ,it can work,but I want to custom the player controler,so I have to add it.Do you have any other way to fix it?Thx.

Comment: What is your device's OS Version?

Comment: @Abbas android 4.4.1

Comment: Thought so. This is a YoutubePlayerAPI issue and doesn't occur from 4.4.4 onwards.

Comment: If you want a workaround it might be possible but may require too much work.

Comment: hi did you find any solution for this issue?